# Is there any way to highlight a particular word in a column of a dataframe before exporting it as Excel worksheet?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, xlsx

The task is to validate some match the keyword with the column values and highlight the matched value and to export it as xlsx spreadsheet...

This is how I'm exporting now..

[image: Export without formatting]

I want to apply some conditional formatting to highlight the matched values.

[image]